# sslscan.c:94:25: fatal error: openssl/err.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated. #163

Tags: sockets, ssl, openssl, network-programming, openssl-engine

I am need to install `sslscan` tool for ssl scanning ([from here](https://github.com/rbsec/sslscan)) in ubuntu virtual machine (virtualbox).

Following their installation instructions provided [here](https://github.com/rbsec/sslscan/blob/master/INSTALL), I installed openssl-chacha from [here](https://github.com/PeterMosmans/openssl/blob/1.0.2-chacha/INSTALL). Note that I am aware that this fork of openssl contains weak cipehrs (I use the tool and openssl for testing-scanning purposes not real application).

Then, after installing the above openssl, the first thing I did is executing: `make`. Note that it is unclear to me when to use these commands that he sslscan mentioned [here](https://github.com/rbsec/sslscan) (I did not execute them). But I want to use the chacha version of openssl:

```
apt-get install build-essential git zlib1g-dev
apt-get build-dep openssl
make static
```

When I try to run the command: `make` I get this error:

```
make: git: Command not found
cc -o sslscan -Wall -Wformat=2 -Wformat-security -pie -z relro -z now -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/ssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/opt/local/lib -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-all -fPIE -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/ssl/include -I/usr/local/ssl/include/openssl -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include/openssl  -DVERSION=\"1.11.11\" sslscan.c -lssl -lcrypto -ldl
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.a(s2_clnt.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:91: recipe for target 'sslscan' failed
make: *** [sslscan] Error 1
```

I am in this directory: `/home/myuser/Downloads/sslscan-master`
I made sure that openssl in:
`/usr/local/ssl`
Can you please point to me what is missing? I am not familiar with Linux system (Windows user) but I prefer to use the tool in Linux. So I will appreciate your help and patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`make: git: Command not found`

So start by installing the `git` command:

```
 apt-get install git
```

(or maybe `git-core`)